# I need to rewrite a particular URL using .htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to rewrite this particular url below as follows

http://myexample.com/forum/addtopics.php?id=22&type=add

**to**

http://myexample.com/forum/category_name/add

I used the rewrite as it

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ forum_add.php?id=$1&type=$2

It is not working for me......
Kindly help me on this....please...

Comment: There is http://myexample.com/forum/addtopics.php?id=22&type=add page exist?????

Answer (score 0):

It's assumed that you have already file called addtopics.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/id/(.*)/type/(.*) addtopics.php?id=$1&type=$2
```

above will form your url

**http://myexample.com/forum/id/22/type/add**

You can then get `id` and `type` Query String parameter by

```
echo $_GET['id']; //will print 22
echo $_GET['type']; //will print add
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: If it fits to your question then you should accept this as an answer and that way this question can be marked as done.